# Getting Non ascii characters as response from python urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://regnskaber.virk.dk/32673592/eGJybHN0b3JlOi8vWC1GNzY5MUY0Ny0yMDE0MDMyOV8xMzQxNThfMTc5L3hicmw.xml")

print (response.getcode())

print (response.readline()) # it gets the first line if you need to the check the output
```

Please help on how to fix this encoding problem.I need to parse XML content.

Comment: @haspander-it's not a bulit in one.I have some restrictions to install or use those libraries.

Comment: @ 9769953 -the output is :  b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed=\xd9r\x1b9\x92\xef\x1d\xd1\xffP\xeb\x87\x8d\x99\x08\x89\xe2}x=\x8a\x95,\xb9\xc7\xdb\xb6\xe5\xb04\x9e\xddG\x90\x05\x920\x8bU\x1c\x00\xa4\xc5\x0f\xd8Oi\x7f\x83\xdf\xf9c\x9b\x99@\xdd\x07\x8b\x94\xdcR\xefL\x84\xc3\x92X@"\xef\x0b@\xf1\xd5\xfdXz\xe2%\xfe\xef\xdc/=_\xfd\xe5\xc5\\\xeb\xd5\xcb\xb3\xb3\xaf_\xbf6\xf0\xe3F gg\xedf\xb3s&|\xa5\x99?\xe1/\xcc\xc8\x97\xd3h,\x8ds\'\x13\xd6p\x17g*\x18\x87#\xc6\xc5#\xb8\xaf\xe5\xf6\x92y\x08\xecv\xce\xb9\xbe\x98L\x82\xb5\xaf\xdf\x04r\xf9\xd6\x9f\x04K

Comment: it is not the right one,i need the XML to parse

Comment: Add extra / new information into your question, not as a comment (comments should not be necessary). A traceback would also have been useful. But see my other comment, and my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic bytes `0x1f8b` at the start of the response indicate zlib compression. Servers will often compress the data for transport, and browsers automatically uncompress them. Here, you'll have to do the second step yourself:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import BytesIO
import gzip
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://regnskaber.virk.dk/32673592/eGJybHN0b3JlOi8vWC1GNzY5MUY0Ny0yMDE0MDMyOV8xMzQxNThfMT\
c5L3hicmw.xml")
print (response.getcode())

data = response.read()

compdata = BytesIO(data)
text = []
for unit in gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compdata):
    text.append(unit)
text = b"".join(text)

tree = ET.fromstring(text)
print(tree)
```

Output:

```
200
<Element '{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl' at 0x104d09098>
```